# How to put a variable as a string parameter in google's API data.addRows('string', value)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to use a variable as a string parameter in data.AddRows like so...

```
   function LanguagesChart(Names, Nums) {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Language');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Employees');

        for (i = 0; i < Names.length - 1; i++) {
            data.addRows([  [Names[i], Nums[i] ] ]);  //This doesn't work
            data.addRows([  [' ' +Names[i], Nums[i] ] ]);  //This doesn't work
            data.addRows([  ['English', Nums[i] ] ]);   //This works
        }
        var options = { 'title': 'Employees Languages', 'width': 400, 'height': 300 };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('LanguageChart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

I see what the problem is. Javascrip is not getting a proper array through the parameter list. I'm using asp.net to send these arrays on the Page_Load and I'm getting these values from a database...

```
      string[] langs = languages.Split(' ');
      string[] Nums = nums.Split(' ');

      string serializedLat = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(langs);
      string serializedLong = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(Nums);

      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LanguagesChart",  "LanguagesChart( " + serializedLat + ", " + serializedLong + ");", true);
```

The Nums array works on the js script but the Names array is not, eventhough I tested it with alert(Names[i] + Nums[i])

Comment: This seems kind of unlikely. What are the contents of `Names`? (a string is a string, whether it is a string literal, a simple variable, or an array element)

Comment: What is `Names` and what is `Nums`? What exactly "does not work"? What is the output you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Names is a string array and Nums is a integer array that I get throught the parrameter list. This crashes the js script and nothing is shown in the output. My expectations is that data.addRows will accept Names[i] as a string but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I was sending an string array through asp.net to javascript and in js I used it as int array although they dont exist in js. The proper way to get these values was...

```
    var num = parseInt(Nums[i]);
    data.addRows([  [Names[i], num ] ]);
```

Glad thats over!